# In a pandas dataframe how do I replicate rows based on a list of values in a column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

| pid | types | other_columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [A,B] | xxxx |
| 2 | [A,B,C] | yyy |

I need to explode the types and duplicate rows for each type

| pid | types | other_columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [A] | xxxx |
| 1 | [B] | xxxx |
| 2 | [A] | yyy |
| 2 | [B] | yyy |
| 2 | [C] | yyy |

Comment: this is [df.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (assuming the `types` column has actual lists - else you'll have to convert the values to lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
out = df.explode('types').assign(types=lambda x: x['types'].map(list))
```

out

```
   pid types other_columns
0    1   [A]          xxxx
0    1   [B]          xxxx
1    2   [A]           yyy
1    2   [B]           yyy
1    2   [C]           yyy
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'pid': [1, 2], 
         'types': [['A','B'], ['A','B','C']], 
         'other_columns': ['xxxx', 'yyy']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```